how to find poolkeys using @solana/web3.js on nextjs
currently, i am using this function to get a poolkeys
export async function fetchPoolKeysMainnet() { const { data } = await axios.get(
"https://api.raydium.io/v2/sdk/liquidity/mainnet.json"); 
console.log({ data });
return data;
}`

but i just want to make another function to get poolkeys from solana api instead i using raydium api, and i try this code,
export async function fetchOpenBookAccounts(
  baseMint: PublicKey,
  quoteMint: PublicKey,
  connection: Connection
) {
  const accounts = await connection.getProgramAccounts(
    PROGRAM_ID[1].OPENBOOK_MARKET,
    {
      commitment: connection.commitment,
      filters: [
        { dataSize: MARKET_STATE_LAYOUT_V3.span },
        {
          memcmp: {
            offset: MARKET_STATE_LAYOUT_V3.offsetOf("baseMint"),
            bytes: baseMint.toBase58(),
          },
        },
        {
          memcmp: {
            offset: MARKET_STATE_LAYOUT_V3.offsetOf("quoteMint"),
            bytes: quoteMint.toBase58(),
          },
        },
      ],
    }
  );

  return accounts.map(({ account }) =>
    MARKET_STATE_LAYOUT_V3.decode(account.data)
  );
}

// Define a function to fetch and decode Market accounts
export async function fetchMarketAccounts(
  base: PublicKey,
  quote: PublicKey,
  connection: Connection
) {
  const accounts = await connection.getProgramAccounts(PROGRAM_ID[1].AmmV4, {
    commitment: connection.commitment,
    filters: [
      { dataSize: LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4.span },
      {
        memcmp: {
          offset: LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4.offsetOf("baseMint"),
          bytes: base.toBase58(),
        },
      },
      {
        memcmp: {
          offset: LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4.offsetOf("quoteMint"),
          bytes: quote.toBase58(),
        },
      },
    ],
  });

  return accounts.map(({ pubkey, account }) => ({
    id: pubkey.toString(),
    ...LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4.decode(account.data),
  }));
}

but is just return []
anyone can help me?
